# Is there a scripting language or parser which has been ported to multiple languages?

Tags: parsing, cross-platform, interpreter

For a research project i'm looking for an interpreter or even a parser for a programming language (doesn't matter what programming language) that has been ported to a number of languages. This probably means the code is small enough to do so.

I know Lisp-ish languages have been ported to a lot of environments, because Lisp is so easy to parse, however I haven't found a single implementation that has been multi targetted. For instance; it is very hard to find a version which works in PHP where the same code (the Lisp which runs on top / is parsed that is) would also work in Python.

Hope someone here can help...

What do I want to do with it? For a tool I'm making, the user group will write tiny pieces of logic; however the system underneath differs while the logic is the same. We don't want to force our users to learn Java, PHP, C#, etc just to write that logic.

Comment: You're assuming that the ported versions all operate identically.  They won't; they'll vary because of the targeted programmming languages are different, and thus require different rules about where you put the pieces. (Even Java isn't write once run everywhere).  You'll have to learn how they are all different.  What exactly are you trying to save?  Trying to do?

Comment: Well I'm looking for a language that has control structures etc, so you can write trivial programs in it and which you can extend with your own API calls. So lets say I have an api:

void helloWorld() { printf("Hello World\n"); }

I want to have a language where I can use this function (by explicitly telling the interpreter) that I can do:

for(i=0;i<10;i++) helloWorld(); 

I'm not sure how this would differ from platform to platform; if this language interpreter would run on Java, C#, C and Ruby, the script code would look the same on all of them and work the same IF I implement like that?

Answer (score 2):

The Lua ([www.lua.org](http://www.lua.org)) scripting language can run from within C and has bindings to Python, php, Java, C#, probably some other languages too. It's a very small interpreter (something like 200k when compiled) because it comes "without batteries" - no builtin functions for some common operations like copying arrays. It should be pretty trivial to add support for embedding in another language, compared to other scripting languages, if need be.